# Add askubuntu.com to Closing > Off-Topic > Migration

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, migration

According to  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:-

> Note that **Ubuntu posts are a special case**. If your question applies to Ubuntu only, or you're looking for answers that are Ubuntu-specific, you should post it on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site.

Also [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) says:-

> Note that http://askubuntu.com is specifically dedicated to Ubuntu questions.

---

Sometimes Users ask question which are Ubuntu specific. When I flagged questions like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209911/unable-to-run-software-updater-ubuntu-software-center-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) as Off-Topic > Migration I found [meta.unix.stackexchange.com](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com) and [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) But [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) is missing.

[image: screenshot]

There are many chance may Ubuntu specific questions are posted here (as well as programming question -stackoverflow) instead.

So, I think one more option should be provided:- belongs on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will repeat the arguments Michael made in the duplicate, just to point out that nothing has changed in the intervening time. There have been a grand total of 10 questions migrated to AU in the past *year*. That's a really, really tiny number of the ~30-40,000 questions posted in that time.

Also, the vast majority of Ubuntu questions are perfectly on topic here since they are about Linux. That the OP happens to be using Ubuntu is usually irrelevant. We only want to migrate those few questions that only concern Ubuntu and which wouldn't be relevant to any other distribution. That is not an easy call to make, it requires a certain level of familiarity with both Ubuntu and other distributions.

In conclusion, I don't think we need this because 1) there really aren't that many questions that deserve migration and 2) I fear that would result in our losing many on topic questions and 3) we would end up migrating things that shouldn't be migrated.

So, if you find posts that belong on AU, just flag them and we'll deal with them.

Comment: Helpful conclusion